# How to run 130 AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, parallel-processing, android-asynctask

I have more than 120 items and need to fetch detail of each by calling API. For parallel execution i have used  asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).

But still app is getting crashed on reaching thread count 133.

Help me to figure out this issue.

Is there any way to do same kind of stuff in different way?

Comment: this is 100% bad idea to try using 130 network threads in parralel. The network protocol itself will not allow that. They should be done let's say on 5 threads in a queue.

Comment: couldn't you have used only one AsyncTask to make all the calls?

Answer (score 0):

In earlier version of Android (Donut and below), multiple AsyncTasks execution were not allowed. The pool size was just 1. But after Donut (1.6) it has been relaxed and now the size is 5, so at most 5 AsyncTasks can run simultaneously.

Check this [Link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/multiple-asynctask-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

i think , to get the best result and do what you want , you have to use RXjava it will make this task a lot easier check  this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-rxjava-in-android-e52ed7ef32e2)

and you can check the official [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)